# how to get inferstrucutre snapshot using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a way to extract the infrastructure details by using terraform

e.g get a list of Linux server's version, firewall policy, opened ports, software packages installed etc..

My aim is to generate a block of code to describe the current server setup, then I can use a check list if validate against the code. therefor security loopholes can be identified and fixed

Comment: Did you tried to search or read about terraform? I think you should edit your question and provide your research you did. Try to follow this link, I hope it may resolve your issue. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand your question. But, there is not such an "automated" way to extract all the details of your not-terraformed infrastructure. Nevertheless, there exists a `terraform import` command with which you can import your existing resource ([here the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html)) to your state file.

Btw, if you are using Oracle Cloud, the [Resource Discovery](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/oci/guides/resource_discovery.html) could be an option.